# instaPy : Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python

I want to install and run instaPy, but I get this error when I try to do so:

```
root@youness:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/InstaPy-master# python quickstart.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 2, in <module>
    from instapy import InstaPy
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/InstaPy-master/instapy/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .instapy import InstaPy
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/InstaPy-master/instapy/instapy.py", line 105
    username: str = None,
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You need to paste your source code and explain what you are trying to achieve, as well as what you have done to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

"""
This template is written by @cormo1990

What does this quickstart script aim to do?
- Basic follow/unfollow activity.

NOTES:
- I don't want to automate comment and too much likes because I want to do
this only for post that I really like the content so at the moment I only
use the function follow/unfollow.
- I use two files "quickstart", one for follow and one for unfollow.
- I noticed that the most important thing is that the account from where I
get followers has similar contents to mine in order to be sure that my
content could be appreciated. After the following step, I start unfollowing
the user that don't followed me back.
- At the end I clean my account unfollowing all the users followed with
InstaPy.
"""

## imports

from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run

## login credentials

insta_username = 'hassan'
insta_password = '123456'

## get an InstaPy session!

## set headless_browser=True to run InstaPy in the background

session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
                  password=insta_password,
                  headless_browser=True)

with smart_run(session):
    """ Activity flow """
    # general settings
    session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled=True,
                                    delimit_by_numbers=True,
                                    max_followers=200000,
                                    min_followers=10,
                                    min_following=10)

```
# activities

""" Massive Follow of users followers (I suggest to follow not less than
3500/4000 users for better results)...
"""
session.follow_user_followers(['rawaa_beauty'], amount=800,
                              randomize=False, interact=False)




""" Joining Engagement Pods...
"""
photo_comments = ['Nice shot! @{}',
    'Awesome! @{}',
    'Cool :thumbsup:',
    'Just incredible :open_mouth:',
    'What camera did you use @{}?',
    'Love your posts @{}',
    'Looks awesome @{}',
    'Nice @{}',
    ':raised_hands: Yes!',
    'I can feel your passion @{} :muscle:']

session.set_do_comment(enabled = False, percentage = 95)
session.set_comments(photo_comments, media = 'Photo')
session.join_pods(topic='food', engagement_mode='no_comments')
```